# How to get column headers of a saved search in NetSuite via suite talk in C#.Net?

Tags: c#, netsuite, suitetalk, saved-searches

I am trying to get information about saved search like how many columns are there in a saved search and their information. 
I have saved search ID and when I do search with netsuite service through code then i am able to get data in a  recordList object, but, each item(row) in list is having many static fields which are null and not used in saved search only the fields that have any value are set in this row object.

Is there any way to get column headers information of a saved search in netsuite via SuiteTalk web services in C#.Net?

Answer (score 0):

First of al, I dont think we can access the SavedSearches from Suite Analytics Connect because the data source to this is Connect Browser, NOT Record Browser.

Saved Searches are created based on the Record Browser! If that might add some value in future.

Please refer to one of the problem that I am having here: [Find the tables and fields in a saved search for Records Browser Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52326698/find-the-tables-and-fields-in-a-saved-search-for-records-browser-item)

I have tried to use Connect but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes using the SuiteTalk library and the RestletsService API.  It returns JSON data you can parse through.  Make sure you have a restlet created to run a saved search on the NetSuite scripts side and return the results in json.

This note is also useful:

> No more than 4000 search results may be returned at one time from
>   `nlobjSearchResultSet.forEachResult(callback)`. Please revise your
>   search criteria or modify the callback logic so that no more than 4000
>   results are returned.

.Net Side

```
RestletsService api = AppSettings.BuildRestletsService;
string json = api.CallRestlet({RESTLET_ID_THAT_RUNS_SAVED_SEARCHES}, {DEPLOY #}, {SAVED_SEARCH_ID});
JArray resultsArray = JArray.Parse(json);
```

Script Side

```
function get_search_data(datain)
{   
    var results = [];
    var savedsearch = nlapiLoadSearch(null, datain.savedsearchid);
    var resultset = savedsearch.runSearch();
    var searchid = 0;
    do {
        var resultslice = resultset.getResults( searchid, searchid+1000 );
        for (var rs in resultslice) {
            results.push( resultslice[rs] );
            searchid++;
        }
    } while (resultslice.length >= 1000);
    return results;
}
```