# Find the tables and fields in a saved search for Records Browser Item

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

The issue we are having is trying to map/relate the fields with different tables from result of saved search created on Records Browser Item(http://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcen...cord/item.html).

We have a retail inventory management system with many modules. So the attempt relating our columns to NetSuite has been going on for a while without any conclusion.

The approach we are trying is to run SuiteScript on the debugger and view the dataset. We were successful those with relatively little volume of data. As the limit is 10,000 rows, we are stuck with Search on Item that returns 1Mil. records. The search returns this volume of data when we add all the search columns. The problem the process of add/removing individual columns is rigorous and just with one column it returns more than 10,000 rows. So it becomes impossible to fetch the data and complete the mapping process.

So I would like to know if there is any way we can only see the schema and their relationships for a saved search?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In SuiteScript 1.0, this can be achieved by a scheduled script that creates multiple CSV files from a saved search ([SuiteAnswers article 36206](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/36206/kw/36206)). You'll have to get around the search limit ([SuiteAnswers article 33496](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/33496/kw/33496)) AND the governance limit ([SuiteAnswers article 23406](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/23406/kw/23406)). If you make the file Available Without Login, you should be able to retrieve the CSV with an HTTP GET request without credentials. However, that will make the data potentially viewable by anyone who knows the URL--a security concern that you will have to consider.

In SuiteScript 2.0, this can probably be achieved with a Map/Reduce script ([SuiteAnswers article 43795](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/43795/kw/map%2Freduce)). This may be a better way to optimize the script, but I have not tested it myself in SuiteScript 2.0.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts and insights!